# Select entity from two tables in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two tables like this:

```
+------------+             +------------+ 
| Parent     |             | Child      | 
+------------+             +------------+ 
|child_id    |------------>|id          | 
|id          |             |date        | 
|name        |             +------------+ 
+------------+
```

I need to extract objects of type `Parent` depending on `date`

This is my query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
      "SELECT p.child_id, p.id, p.name from Parent p, Child c 
       WHERE p.child_id = c.id
       AND c.date between :date and CURRENT_DATE ");

query.setTimestamp("date",new Date(2012,1,1));

List<Parent> objList = query.list()     // List<Object[]> instead of List<Parent>
```

I've been trying for hours already and I couldn't get any closer then this. Can you tell me what is wrong with my query or how can I achieve my goal?

**EDIT:** I found a problem: `new Date(2012,1,1)` was creating a date of year 3092, I fixed it by adding the date through `java.sql.Date`

The result is an `List<Object[]>`, I know I could iterate each objects vector, and create a new Parent with values from objects, but isn't there a way I can get directly a `Parent` object from query list?

Comment: Fire your query in database, to see if it actually gets some data. Another thing is it should be `query.list()` and not `query.list`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the query works perfectly in db.

Comment: Alternatively try `session.createSQLQuery()` for once if it works. Once you use that the query should be replaced by your table name rather than Entites.

Comment: show us the output you are getting and what is wrong with it

Comment: @Philipp Sander, the output is an empty list, as I stated in the query comments

Comment: does it work without the date restriction?

Comment: Did you try replacing "CURRENT_DATE" by ":endDate" and set this value using "query.setParameter(...) as for the 1st Date param ?

Comment: @Snorky35 just tried, same result

Comment: what Date class are you using?

Comment: @PhilippSander java.util.Date

Comment: then it must be the data in your database.

Comment: I found out java.util.Date's constructor doesn't work very well and fixed that problem with java.sql.Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two problems and this is the solution to each:

1. **Date problem**

`java.util.Date(int year, int month, int day)` should be avoided as it turns out it messes up the date. You can solve this problem by using `java.util.Calendar` and set the date to it.

Then you need to convert it to java.sql.Date to match the query syntax

2. **Query the list of entitys and not object[]**

I managed to get a List directly from the query (without resorting to manually iterating the list of `Objects[]` and creating `Parent` entities myself) using this query:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select p.* from myscheme.Parent p, myscheme.Child c
     WHERE p.child_id = c.id AND c.date > :date ")
    .addEntity(Parent.class);
query.setTimestamp("date",sqlDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Time is cut off if you use this call:

```
query.setDate(...);
```

Instead, use the following call:

```
query.setTimestamp(...)
```

Try also to use [Criteria Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Such as:

```
criteria.add(Expression.eq("date", new Date()));
```

---

If the query works without date restrictions, you can make some experiments by comparing the dates. 
For example, as follows:

```
...
Date customDate = new Date(2012, 1, 1);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");    

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("from Child c");
query.append(" where c.date >= '" + simpleDateFormat.format(customDate) + "'");

Query result = session.createQuery(query.toString());
List resultList = result.list();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query.setParameter("date",new Date(2012,1,1));
```

use the setParameter method instead of setDate

Comment: I already tried `setDate`, `setTime`, `setTimestamp`, `setParameter`. The result is the same